# Vue js CLI 2 import and use javascript plugin

Tags: vue.js, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

recently I started to work on Vue js and I want to use a javascript plugin like [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

also I installed as:

```
npm install isotope-layout
```

here is my question, how can I use the plugin in my component?

I followed the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dede89/1a32bzm5/) but I got an error:

> can't find #main element

thank you

Comment: You can use it however you want. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you are specifically trying to achieve and describe what isn't working as expected.

Comment: @thanksd in Jquery we know how to use `$('.grid').isotope({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});`

but in Vue js??????!!!!

Comment: I'm still unsure what your question is. Your error means that you don't have an element in your project with `id="main"` (like you do in the jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use it like this:

```
// ES6
import isotope from 'isotope-layout'
...
export default {
      components: {
        isotope,
      }
```